# Return value from Apex Class to the Client-side Lightning Controller

Tags: apex, lightning

Hi i have a problem with principles how to pass return value from apex method into the client.

I have an Apex class to create current Datetime

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Datetime calcPuDate() {
    Datetime puDate = Datetime.now();
    System.debug('PU IS YES #### ' + puDate);
    return puDate;
}
```

And i want to send puDate into the helper, where i have a function where i am calling apex method.

```
    calcDate : function (cmp, event, helper) {
          console.log("### calc date time in helper 1");
          var action = cmp.get("c.calcPuDate");
          setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
                var status = actionResult.getState();
                console.log(actionResult.getState());
                console.log('Datetime vracene z APEXU ### ' + actionResult.getReturnValue())
         console.log(response.getReturnValue());

          });
          $A.enqueueAction(action);
console.log("### calc date time in helper 2");

},
```

But there is a problem with executing, it calling Action failed [setCallback is not defined] in client side controller function, where i need to set result into the field value.

```
passDateHere : function(cmp, event, helper) {               
var allCells = cmp.find("table-cell");
                if (allCells != null) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < allCells.length; i++) {
                        var cell = allCells[i];
                        if (cell.get("v.id") == event.getSource().get("v.id") && cell.get("v.fieldName") == 'Date_of_PU__c')  {
                            if ((cell.get("v.value")) == null) {
                                console.log("### calc date time in controller");
                                helper.calcDate(cmp);
    //                            allCells[i].set("v.value", today);
                            } else {
                                console.log("nic nesetovat");
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, did you know that you can get the current date and time using only Javascript with: `var currentdate = new Date();`

Then, the problem in your code is that the `setCallback` method is only available using your `action` variable with: `action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {`

Comment: yes i know about `var currentdate = new Date();` but its sending it into apex in wrong format, its putting into the string letter "T". for example 2018-09-13T09:37:08.792Z